# Park assist cameras for lane change

Tags: nissan, camera, x-trail

I've got a Nissan X-Trail 2014 (Australia). Under 10 km/h, the park assist cameras can be used. They're really great for showing a 360° view around the car, so I was wondering whether there was any way to turn them on while driving to help with checking blind spots when changing lanes?

Comment: No, it is a safety issue.

Comment: there is a way to put the display unit into a diagnostic mode that shows all the camera outputs. but it's impractical to use when driving as you need both hands to do it.

Answer (score 1):

My 2016 Toyota RAV4 hybrid also has the 360 degree view implemented by using 4 cameras. I have noted that in order to see the vehicle next to you in a parking spot, you have to be really close to that other vehicle. At typical highway speeds, the lanes are so far away from each other that the 360 degree view wouldn't show the other car.

There is a technology that helps lane change, and it is called blind spot monitor (BSM). My Toyota RAV4 has BSM, too. I really like that feature, as it makes lane changes a lot easier.